# Failure deploying AppEngine version because of Cloud Storage JSON API enablement

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine, google-managed-vm, managed-vm

I am trying to deploy to Google AppEngine. (More precisely: Managed VM.)

I ran  `gcloud preview app deploy d:\dev\mytest\yaml-war\app.yaml --version=joshua20160316d --project=mytest-test1`.

After about 30 minutes, it failed.

The error  message directs me to  log lines in the Cloud Developer Console (see below)  which tell me that access to the Cloud Storage JSON API needs to be enabled. However, the Developer Console shows that the Cloud Storage JSON API  is already enabled. (See screenshot.)

Also, note that this works for other team members; and that the same command against a different project also succeeded. So, it is some sort of setting specific to the project and my account, but I don't know what.

What do I need to do to make this work?

[image: screenshot; API is enabled]

```
Failure setting up GCS logging: failed to create GCS logging client: error creating logfile: googleapi: Error 403: Access Not Configured. The API (Cloud Storage JSON API) is not enabled for your project. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your configuration., accessNotConfigured
{
 metadata: {
  severity:     "INFO"
  projectId: "mytest-test1"
  serviceName: "cloudbuild.googleapis.com"
  labels: {     
    cloudbuild.googleapis.com/build_id:
  "49697866-90f8-4771-82ef-7fe149f1d926"
  }
  timestamp: "2016-03-16T14:19:10.940059809Z"
  projectNumber: "232473234717"
 }
 textPayload: "Failure setting up GCS logging: failed to create GCS logging client: error creating logfile: googleapi: Error 403: Access Not Configured. The API (Cloud Storage JSON API) is not enabled for your project. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your configuration., accessNotConfigured"
 insertId: "41697866-90f8-4771-82ef-8fe149f1d926-0"
 log: "41697866-90f8-4771-82ef-8fe149f1d926"
}
```

The local log includes the following.

```
Operation [operations/build/mytest-test1/MmFmNjFhNGQtZDU2Yi00NzczLWI5NTItNWYyNGYyZGYyM2FkOlAT] complete. Result: {
    "metadata": {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.devtools.cloudbuild.v1.BuildOperationMetadata", 
        "build": {
            "finishTime": "2016-03-16T13:35:28.453575Z", 
            "status": "FAILURE", 
            "timeout": "600.000s", 
            "startTime": "2016-03-16T13:35:28.199428Z", 
            "workerId": "worker-74ace662-26dc-47c5-b23b-0886f61a5fbe", 
            "logsBucket": "staging.mytest-test1.appspot.com", 
            "userId": "846527075559", 
            "results": {}, 
            "id": "2af61a4d-d57b-4773-b952-5e24f2df23ad", 
            "buildReceipt": {
                "clientId": "32555940559"
            }, 
            "source": {
                "storageSource": {
                    "object": "mytest-test1.default.joshua20160316d", 
                    "bucket": "staging.mytest-test1.appspot.com"
                }
            }, 
            "steps": [
                {
                    "args": [
                        "appengine.gcr.io/gcloud/mytest-test1.default.joshua20160316d"
                    ], 
                    "name": "gcr.io/cloud-builders/dockerizer"
                }
            ], 
            "sourceProvenance": {
                "resolvedStorageSource": {
                    "generation": "1458135324271000", 
                    "object": "mytest-test1.default.joshua20160316d", 
                    "bucket": "staging.mytest-test1.appspot.com"
                }
            }, 
            "projectId": "mytest-test1", 
            "images": [
                "appengine.gcr.io/gcloud/mytest-test1.default.joshua20160316d"
            ], 
            "projectNum": "232473234717", 
            "foremanId": "cloud-build/foreman.server/ir/0", 
            "createTime": "2016-03-16T13:35:26.145234Z"
        }
}, 
"done": true, 
"name": "operations/build/mytest-test1/MmFmNjFhNGQtZDU2Yi00NzczLWI5NTItNWYyNGYyZGYyM2FkOlAT", 
"error": {
    "message": "Build failed; check build logs for details", 
    "code": 2
}
```

}

Comment: See a different failure, this time on Linux with local Docker build: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36054793/failure-deploying-appengine-version-because-of-timeout

Answer (score 2):

This may sound silly, but have you tried disabling and re-enabling the API?
https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/storage_api/overview?project=232474234717 (you have a screenshot of this). [yes, tried; didn't help]

Second, you could try specifying your own GCS bucket with the `--bucket` flag.  By default the build uses a special bucket that is automatically set up for your project.

Finally, if you specify `--use_cloud_build=0`, you will enable the legacy build system where a VM will spin up in your project, do the build, and then shut down.  The newer cloud build service is intended to replace the legacy system and is 1-2 minutes faster.

I'm sorry you are hitting a roadblock here.

Comment: I tried disabling/re-enabling. Same problem. Similar though not identical log line. Note that other team members do succeeds, so it's not true that the project has never been used.

"Cloud Storage JSON API has not been used in project 232474234717 before or it is disabled"

Comment: I can understand how this would be frustrating. Knowing that other team members can build against the same project is useful information. The account that is getting rejected by GCS is actually a service account attached to your project. When your teammates do a build against the same project, their builds would be run under the same service account as your build.

Comment: As another data point -- I compared my permissions in the project in which my build fails and another in which it succeeds, and I am "owner" in both.

But as you say, it is a service account that is being blocked, which makes it more mysterious why my build would fail on permissions while my colleague's would not.